# SQL Server Backup to Azure Blob URL fails with 500 error

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am attempting to backup a large database to my Azure Blob container. I successfully backup around 31 other small databases ranging from 1Mb to 600mb (.Bak file size).

However, the big main database is 32Gb (When seeing the properties) and the latest local backup file is 16Gb. So I'm assuming SQL Server is attempting to upload 16Gb to Azure Blob Storage.

My backup command is:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [MyDatabase] TO URL =
'https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/dbbackups/mycontainer/mydatabase.bak' WITH CREDENTIAL = 'AzureDBBackupsContainer'
   , FORMAT
   , COMPRESSION;
```

All the databases upload, except the big one, and it errors with:

> ```
> The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 3202)
> ```

Does anyone know a solution for this? I think it's timing out on a 16Gb upload.

Comment: there should be more information about the error in Windows event logs.

Comment: @BrunoFaria - On the SQL Server, I see an error 500 from remote server. Is there a way to see a 'windows event log' on Azure? I've checked the storage account, and see no errors there. Is there a form of 'Windows Event Log' on Azure I can look at?